# Export to WXR for pages containing script and iframe tags

Tags: multisite, migration, export, iframe

I've noticed that when importing content from a WordPress site which has  tags embedded in the page content, the operation seems to have stripped out all `<script>` and `<iframe>` tags. I imported the content using the default that is installable via the tools admin screen.

Is this expected behaviour and is there a way round it? The export is from a single site to a subdomain site within a multisite install. I can't run wp-cli on the origin site as I don't have SSH access there.

I've confirmed that the tags are missing in the `wp_posts` table after importing and that they are present in the XML export file.

One possible cause which occurs to me is that the `<script>` tags in the original content contain CDATA sections e.g.

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
(function()); //more code in here
// ]]></script>
```

So perhaps the importer doesn't deal with these well. I'll be advising against pasting scripts into the page editor but need a fix in the meantime.

Comment: "I've confirmed that the tags are missing in the wp_posts table" - before exporting or after importing?

Comment: @kaiser thanks. I updated the question to clarify that.

Comment: Wait a second: "when exporting [...] the operation seems to have stripped out all [...] tags" and then later on you say "[...] they are present in the XML export file". So what's the case now?

Comment: @kaiser Sorry, I wrote the question in a bit of a rush. It seems that the tags were exported ok but then are stripped when importing

Comment: "In a rush" never is a good way to write a question (see [ask] for further help) :P Anyway, it's clear now that you have a problem with the importer. Which one are you using? The default that is installable via the tools admin screen? Please keep in mind that we are already confronted with a comment explosion, so please take you time for the next (and hopefully final) [edit] of your question.